# Does not contain anything else than value matched by regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression that matches for dollar amount
`\$[?\-\s\d,.]+`

How to check if a string does not contain any thing else than value matched to above regex?

Comment: Wrap it in `^...$`, which are beginning and end of the string

Answer (score 2):

```
^\$[?\s\d,.-]+$
```

This should do it for you.These anchors will make sure no partial matches are made.

```
^ assert position at start of a line
$ assert position at end of a line
```